# Typo3 solr extension not indexing page contents?

Tags: php, solr, typo3, typoscript

I have successfully able to configure solr in my local machine.Also i have installed solr extension in my local tyo3 installation and tried to index the all the pages . But i am getting an error as given below . Can some please help me with this .

```
My Solr version is 4.4.8
Typo3 verson 6.1
PHP 5.3
EXT:solr 3
open jdk 6
```

Typoscript configuration

```
plugin.tx_solr.solr.port = 8983
plugin.tx_solr.solr.useCurlHttpTransport = 1
plugin.tx_solr.solr.host = 192.168.0.207
plugin.tx_solr.solr.path = /solr/#/~cores/
config.index_enable = 1 
plugin.tx_solr.logging.indexing.queue.pages = 1
plugin.tx_solr.logging.indexing.pageIndexed = 1


1331837081: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed indexing page Index Queue item 631' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/IndexQueue/PageIndexer.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/IndexQueue/PageIndexer.php(64): Tx_Solr_IndexQueue_PageIndexer->indexPage(Object(Tx_Solr_IndexQueue_Item), 0, '0')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3conf/ext/solr/Scheduler/IndexQueueWorkerTask.php(115): Tx_Solr_IndexQueue_PageIndexer->index(Object(Tx_Solr_IndexQueue_Item))
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3conf/ext/solr/Scheduler/IndexQueueWorkerTask.php(78): Tx_Solr_Scheduler_IndexQueueWorkerTask->indexItem(Object(Tx_Solr_IndexQueue_Item))
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3conf/ext/solr/Scheduler/IndexQueueWorkerTask.php(57): Tx_Solr_Scheduler_IndexQueueWorkerTask->indexItems()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php(157): Tx_Solr_Scheduler_IndexQueueWorkerTask->execute()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Controller/SchedulerModuleController.php(826): TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler->executeTask(Object(Tx_Solr_Scheduler_IndexQueueWorkerTask))
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Controller/SchedulerModuleController.php(186): TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController->executeTasks()
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Controller/SchedulerModuleController.php(137): TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController->getModuleContent()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3/sysext/scheduler/mod1/index.php(36): TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController->main()
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/layerslider-6.1.5/typo3/mod.php(41): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling logging in Ext:solr to see more details about your issue?

Comment: @sreuter: When i checked the log in typo3 i can see an error 
 `08-07-14 13:50:57   solr Exception while adding documents ClassLoader_Typo3PageIndexer_3be674367a9bf6be7262.php, line 313`   


`08-07-14 13:50:57   solr Querying Solr using POST SolrService.php, line 402 `

Comment: Is the Solr index completly empty or are there any pages indexed?

Comment: @sreuter after debugging a lot i managed to index some of the pages. But still i am getting error some of the pages.I have one small question for you. Do you hvae any idea to change /update?wt=json to /update?wt=xml in typo3 solr extension ?? If you know about this , kindly help me .

Comment: It seems that the TYPO3 Extension for Solr can only work with 'json' as value for that. It is set as constant in code. As reasoning is [this link](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/issues/detail?id=6#c1) given.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by switching the openjdk version . I updated my jdk version and everything seems to work as intended . If you have custom columns to index , Then add those custom column in solr.xml and then re-run the configuration once again .

```
My Solr version is 4.9.0
Typo3 verson 6.1
PHP 5.3
EXT:solr 3
open jdk > 6
```

I hope this make sense .